# Using a variable for mail attachment path: $mailer->AddAttachment($file_variable);

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to build an automated email that will send attachments based on a variable that contains the relative path to a file using PHPmailer. The file path is stored in a table in MYSQL. I want to fetch the file path for each email sent using a while loop.  Anyone ever done this? The emails get sent fine but without the attachments and the following error is printed:

Could not access file: $filepath

The lines of code in question are lines 11, 12 and 27. Thanks for your help.

```
1

 require("PHPMailer_v5.1 2/class.phpmailer.php");
    2    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    3    $to = $row['email'];
    4    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    5    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    6    $msg = $row['msg'];
    7    $id = $row['id'];
    8
    9    //the code in question -lines 11 and 12:
    10
    11   $filepath= $row['filepath'];
    12    $filename= $row['filename'];
    13
    14  $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    15  $mailer->IsSMTP();
    16  $mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
    17  $mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    18  $mailer->Username = 'xx';  // Sender's gmail address
    19  $mailer->Password = 'xx';  // Sender's gmail password
    20  $mailer->From = 'xx';  // Sender's email address
    21  $mailer->FromName = 'xx'; // This is the from name in the email
    22  $mailer->Body = "$msg";
    23  $mailer->Subject = "$id";
    24  $mailer->AddAddress('xx');  // Recipient
    25
    26   //Applying the variables fetched from the database - can this be done?
    27  $mailer->AddAttachment('$filepath', '$filename');
    28  
    29    if(!$mailer->Send())
    30  //more code...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`27  $mailer->AddAttachment('$filepath', '$filename');`
should be
`27  $mailer->AddAttachment($filepath, $filename);`
otherwise you just pass "$filepath" and "$filename" to AddAtachment, not the actual data behind the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$mailer->AddAttachment($filepath, $filename);
```

Comment: Sure.  Remember as the question asker you have the right to mark the correct answer as the right one.  This gives you rep and give the person who answered it a pat on the back.  It also helps people to know that the asker of the question found x answer to be the best.